# problems with dict.keys not printing a list but printing the view of the list

Tags: dictionary, python-3.x, key

I keep trying to get a list of keys out of my dict by using dict.keys but it keeps giving me:

`def reverse(PB = {'l': 3, 'y':1, 'u':2}):
    print(PB.keys())`

prints:

`dict_keys(['u', 'l', 'y'])`

I've never had this issue before I have a python version beyond 2.7... any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3 returns [view objects](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views):

> The objects returned by `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()` are *view objects*. They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes.

You can convert them into a list (the Python 2 behavior) by passing them into `list()`:

```
>>> d = {'l': 3, 'y':1, 'u':2}
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys(['y', 'l', 'u'])
>>> list(d.keys())
['y', 'l', 'u']
```

Also, be careful with passing [mutable objects as default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument):

```
>>> def reverse(PB={'l': 3, 'y':1, 'u':2}):
...     PB['l'] += 4
...     
...     print(PB)
... 
>>> reverse()
{'y': 1, 'l': 7, 'u': 2}
>>> reverse()
{'y': 1, 'l': 11, 'u': 2}
>>> reverse()
{'y': 1, 'l': 15, 'u': 2}
```

I'd default to `None` instead:

```
def reverse(PB=None):
    if PB is None:
        PB = {'l': 3, 'y':1, 'u':2}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Was a big help.